# Given two odd primes, $p\neq q$, prove that there are no primitive roots $\mod(pq)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Given two odd primes, $p\neq q$, prove that there are no primitive roots $\mod(pq)$

I don't know where to start with this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $a$ be primitive root $\mod(pq)$

then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod (p)$ and $a^{q-1}\equiv 1\mod (q)\implies a^{lcm(p-1)(q-1)}\equiv 1\mod (pq)$

also $lcm(p-1)(q-1)<(p-1)(q-1)$ so the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $\phi(pq)$ is an even multiple of both $\phi(p)=p-1$ and $\phi(q)=q-1$.
- Check what happens when you raise a residue class to power $\phi(pq)/2$.